# Python and JSON via Redis does not seem to work

Tags: python, json

I am having trouble with Python and JSON.

1) I send a dictionary to Redis via JSON. I use JSON to dump the dict on the producer and loads from consumer:

```
#This is a dictionary
args = {"last_observed_date": "2014-04-08T02:05:00", "tau": 2, "interval": 5, "backcast": 5, "series": "exr:EUR_USD:2014-04-08T02:05:00", "K": 5, "is_difference": false, "M": 3, "is_log": false, "last_time": null, "pair": "EUR_USD", "granularity": "minute", "series_name": "closeBid", "method": [{"ols": {"alpha": 0.5}}]}
```

Producer server:

```
args = json.dumps(args)
r.lpush(model_queue,args)
```

Consumer server:

```
args = r.brpop(model_queue,0)[1]
args = json.loads(args)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/forex-trading/chaos/chaos_worker.py", line 38, in <module>
    data = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

My question is why, when I dump a dictionary as a string, I can't decode when retrieved from Redis?

Flow is this: dictionary to string -> redis -> string to dictionary.  I dump on the producer and load on the consumer.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What type are you passing to `json.loads`?

Comment: Its a dictionary.  a hash

Comment: You're pushing on one side and popping off the other. Are you sure you're popping what you think off the queue? Maybe you had some bad data on there. Well, you almost certainly did - `x==json.loads(json.dumps(x))`

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass a dictionary to json.loads, you have to pass a json string. try:

```
args = json.loads(json.dumps(args))
```

Comment: I am dumping the hash on the producer and loading on the consumer.

Comment: i am interested to know what type of object you get in args = r.brpop(model_queue,0)[1] what is args? can you do a type(args) or similar and find out?